# What does "not open" and "where" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> If this application is **not open where you run the task**, an error
>   occurs.

I think sometimes people use "where" instead of "when". Does "where" in this sentence mean "when"? And does "not open" mean "not opened"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here **open** is used as adjective meaning **ready to be used or provide service** and where is used for any application,program or any other platform in computer system or any device. In this case Where is not used instead of when.But if you say

> If this application is not open when you run the task. Here **when** refers to some time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to whether the person who wrote this means "when", but as a matter of meaning in general, "where" means something different from "when". "Where" would mean some sort of sense of location, such as "If you aren't running the application on the same computer", or "If you aren't running the application in the same command line instance".